# Continuous integration using REST api in vf page

Tags: asynchronous, continuation

I have been asked a question in continuous integration. First let me give some background.

In continuous integration api call we can call 3 webservice urls at a time and process response in another call back method.According to this document

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_overview.htm

it says

> You can make up to three asynchronous callouts in a single
>   continuation. Add these callout requests to the same continuation by
>   using the addHttpRequest method of the Continuation class. The
>   callouts run in parallel for this continuation and suspend the
>   Visualforce request. Only after the external service returns all
>   callouts, the Visualforce process resumes.

so my now my question is when 3 api's are called in single method we get the responses immediately from external webservice so where does salesforce store this response before calling callback method is it?somewhere in cache or any memory is allocated temporarily to hold the responses before showing it in front end. Basically i want to know how salesforce manages continuous integration at backend.

Answer (score 2):

A [`Continuation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_overview.htm) has nothing to do with [continuous integration](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/05/continuous-integration-with-salesforce-dx.html).

From the perspective of the on-platform developer, the response data is stored in the `Continuation` object, and is accessed via [`getResponse()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Continuation.htm). The underlying implementation is not documented publicly, as far as I know. In general, you should not expect to be privy to the details of how the platform implements its functionality, and it may change from release to release.